# How to add an if staging check to Capistrano task?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Right now in Capistrano I have it doing

```
execute "echo #{fetch(:stage)}"
```

Which echoes out "staging"

On the very next line I have

```
if fetch(:stage) == "staging"
```

Which never equals true. I tried changing it to `if "staging == "staging"` and it enters the body of it. Uh, what gives and how do I do a check to only run one line of code for staging.

Comment: try `execute "echo #{fetch(:stage).inspect}"`. Stage might be a symbol.

Comment: "which never runs" - Never runs at all or never enters body of this if? Be precise.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yep that did it! I had no idea about inspect. Thank you! Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept it. Sorry, very new to Ruby, using Capistrano to deploy a PHP project so writing this config file is all new to me.

Comment: PHP doesn't have symbols, IIRC, so the confusion is understandable :) But doesn't PHP have its own deploy tools?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not many, and the ones I tried were all either paid/hosted or garbage feature wise. Got Capistrano fully configured now though, which was a blast. Hoping to learn more Ruby soon. =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fetch(:stage)` is likely a symbol (it's been a while since I used capistrano). To verify this, use a more precise string representation:

```
execute "echo #{fetch(:stage).inspect}"
```

I'm betting it will print `:staging`. In which case you need to do

```
if fetch(:stage) == :staging
```