# Ruby rake tasks on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm using capistrano to deploy my site to staging and production servers. I want to use something similar to the below to check if I'm deploying on staging or production and run the appropriate commands. For some reason, the comparison operators aren't working. Am I comparing the wrong variable value types, or something similar?

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :published do
        on release_roles :all do

            if :deploy_to == "/home/master/applications/STAGING/public_html/"
                # RUN THIS COMMAND...
                execute "cd /in/to/a/directory/on/staging/server/"
            end

            if :deploy_to == "/home/master/applications/PRODUCTION/public_html/"
                # RUN THIS COMMAND...
                execute "cd /in/to/a/directory/on/production/server/"
            end

        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49677479/5538221